# Problem moving checkbox and the text to the left

Tags: html, css

I need to modify an existing codes. That is to add a checkbox and texts underneath a reset password field (see the image). I have to keep the existing look. The existing codes are wrapped between div align=center tags and I'm not allowed to change this because I have to make sure this page looks the same to all other pages, all form fields and texts are centered.
This is just a front end form modification and I'm not good with css so I'm desperately need help, thank you!!!
NOTE: Not sure how to include my codes here so I get rid of the < > signs from the codes

existing code:

```
         <h4>Enter your NEW password here</h4>
            <form name="pswreset" id="pswreset" action="pswreset_action.cfm" method="post">
            <fieldset>
              <input type="password" placeholder="Your New Password" name="pwd" tabindex="7" id="psw-repeat" required>
            </fieldset>
            <fieldset>
             <input type="checkbox" id="showpsw"/>  show password
            </fieldset>
            <fieldset>
              <button>SUBMIT</button>
            </fieldset>
         </form>
```

[image]

Comment: Attach here the code that assembles the elements in the screen you took

Comment: There are two options to format code, first one is to indent code 4 spaces, and the second one is to select all text you want to format as code, and click on the `{}` icon which is in the header of text editor.

Comment: Where is the existing css